# Remove Objects items from a list that are in another other two lists

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq

I'm new to C#, and I'm updating to mess with lists.
I currently have this event Object.
From it, I need to generate a new String list.
I must remove all emails that are on Data3 and that are on Data1 and Data2.

```
{
  "event": 
    {
      "userData": [
        {
          "Data1": [
            {
              "comentario": "",
              "email": "erick@gmail.com",
              "name": "erick"
            },
            {
              "comentario": "",
              "email": "isa@gmail.com",
              "name": "isa"
            }
          ],
          "Data2": [
            {
              "comentario": "",
              "email": "erick@gmail.com",
              "name": "erick"
            }
          ],
          "Data3": [
            {
              "comentario": "",
              "email": "erick@gmail.com",
              "name": "erick"
            },
            {
              "comentario": "",
              "email": "joseph@gmail.com",
              "name": "joseph"
            },
            {
              "comentario": "",
              "email": "ju@gmail.com",
              "name": "ju"
            },
            {
              "comentario": "",
              "email": "isa@gmail.com",
              "name": "isa"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

The end result would be this:

Newlist = ["joseph@gmail.com", "ju@gmail.com"]

As "erick@gmail.com" and "isa@gmail.com" are in Data1 and Data2, I should remove both from Data3, and return only the others.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Are you receiving this JSON from a somewhere? Are you deserializing it to a model? -- What do you want to do with it? Generate a List of unique email addresses? Generate a new JSON with just one `Data` object that contain an array of objects unique in relation to their content? Other? What does *remove* mean here? -- Post your best shot at it, it's simpler to understand your intentions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude elements from a list that are found in another list just use

```
var result= list1.Except(list2);
```

Comment: Without further explanation from OP - this is a correct answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Enumerable.Except` method as mentioned in previous answer. A complete example is given below:

```
List<String> list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("Apple");
list1.Add("Ball");
list1.Add("Car");

List<String> list2 = new List<string>();
list2.Add("Cat");
list2.Add("Dog");
list2.Add("Mouse");
list2.Add("Ball");

List<String> newList = list2.Except(list1).ToList();//don't forget to parse new list
```