# How to compare and remove items from lists in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to c# development. I want to compare and remove list items that already exist in another list. Is there any built in method to do that instead of doing it using loop?

Comment: You can use Linq and Except. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0 - var newList = list1.Except(list2);

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72608973/remove-objects-items-from-a-list-that-are-in-another-other-two-lists/72611464#72611464)
answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

The `List` object has a `RemoveAll` method which can remove all elements of the list which match the predicate.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-6.0

You can also use the `except` method, answered here: [Remove items from one list in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745544/remove-items-from-one-list-in-another)

Comment: Be aware that an in-place modification of a list (as per `RemoveAll()` is much more efficient than creating a new list.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list1 = { /* first list */ };
var list2 = { /* second list to remove from first */ };

list1 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```